# What is the behaviour of comparing pointer to static variable?

Tags: c, pointers, static, comparison

I have read something like pointer are equals if:
They both point to the same address, or the same function.

Does it work with `static` functiona, which are equally named but have different adresses?

**main.c**:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void *p1;
extern void *p2;

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", p1 == p2);
    return 0;
}
```

**A.h**:

```
static void f() {}
```

**B.c**:

```c
#include "A.h"
void *p1 = &f;
```

**C.c**:

```c
#include "A.h"
void *p2 = &f;
```

What will this code print, or is it maybe undefined behaviour?

Comment: Why not? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It print that they are not equal. But I don't know if it's standardized / U.B., or what if the behaviour in case of optimizations

Comment: Please show the full code, and what was actually printed. My test (a single code module) shows they are the same. BTW please do not put the function implementation in a header file. You might get two of them. The `p1` and `p2` in `main.c` are also different variables to those in `B.c` and `C.c`.

Comment: Since the `p1` and `p2` in `main.c` are static, they are automatically initialised to `NULL` and so they must be equal, because they are different variables from those which are set in the other modules.

Comment: This is the full code. I add the "extern" keyword which was missing. Sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. p1 and p2 are not static (I changed it), the static function is defined in .h like static function are.

Comment: Oh, now you have changed the code. They are different because you have two functions named `f`, one defined in `B.c` and the other in `C.c`. Don't put function definitions in a header, only their declarations (prototype).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will have undefined behaviour, but for the very reason that the C standard does not specify what will happen when a *pointer to function* is converted to a *pointer to `void`*.

Converting convertibility of pointer to a function to a pointer to `void` is listed as a common extension ([C11 J.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.7)), and POSiX requires it. However, it probably still should use an explicit cast.

---

Two pointers to a *function* will compare equal to each other only if they point to the same function ([C11 6.5.9p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p6))

> Two pointers compare equal if and only [...], both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, [...]

Two functions with internal linkage in different translation units are distinct, hence pointers to them should compare not equal; and the `void *` conversion of them likewise, if round-trip is guaranteed.

---

I read the standard as such that if the linker *merges* the two definitions with identical code, the implementation is not a conforming one. ([C11 6.2.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2p2))

Comment: Ok, thank you, I think it answered the question, regardless of the bad pointer conversion

Comment: @Antti Haapala: I am not 100% sure of the part *Two functions with internal linkage in different translation units are distinct*. Could a link time optimizer, such as that used for `-flto` merge identical functions?

Comment: @chqrlie well, everything is possible but my reading is that it wouldn't be conforming, because of **if and only if**... - on the other hand for *strings* it is said that it is not specified whether they're distinct.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: interesting... two structures with the same definition represent the same object type, but two functions with the same definition are different instances.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- the function is defined `static` in each module, the compiler will produce a different object for each module, which the linker might or might not merge given the identical code for both, regardless of their identical `static` name. However such an optimization seems to be non-conforming, so the functions should have a different address.
- the pointers have type `void *`, which is not guaranteed to hold a function pointer unambiguously. As a matter of fact, the C Standard does not define the behavior of converting a pointer to function to a pointer to object type. Thus, unless you assume an extension to the C Standard, the behavior is undefined. You should define `p1` with type `void (*p1)();` etc.

The program will most likely output `0`, but this behavior is not guaranteed until you fix the type issue.